# difficulty to create a sandbox directory for new packages

Tags: ros-fuerte, create

[image: Rosanswers logo]

all former setting has been done. after 'rosws set ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox' it comes to 'rosws: error: No scm or localname provided'
I do not know why  need your kind help.....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59386/difficulty-to-create-a-sandbox-directory-for-new-packages/) by [guodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4544/guodi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2013-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to specify that you don't want a VCS directory by:

```
rosws set DIR_NAME --detached
```

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2013-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Haojun Guan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2244/haojun-guan/) on 2013-06-05**:
still got the same error